# Is it possible to auto snap Windows 8.1 metro app upon launch?

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro

Is it possible to launch Windows 8.1 metro app, say Music, so that it automatically snap at the side of the desktop, without needing the user to place it there?
Can it be done programmatically?